# Video.js styles not overriding default video styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, video

I'm working on a website here and I have discovered the video.js plugin for the next part of my project. I have done everything exactly as the video.js site said to do in order to get it to set up on the page properly, and even moved external file links around on the page, and that didn't affect anything. I just want to be able to style it so that it looks similar to the website that it is on. Sample code below. Also I'm using bootstrap 3.0 I don't know if that is a problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?=$up_level?>assets/css/bootstrap.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?=$up_level?>assets/video-js/video-js.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2'>
            </div>
            <div class='col-lg-4'>
                <video id='intro-video' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' preload='auto' width='640' height='264' poster='' data-setup='{controls:true}' >
                <source src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4' type='video/mp4' />
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='<?=$up_level?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='<?=$up_level?>assets/video-js/video.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

for other references the

```
<?=$up_level?>
```

is just a directory level calculator. There is no problem with that function. Also I have double and triple checked the video-js folder is in its proper directory location, and is loading. So again just to recap, using the video.js extension, it isn't letting me style anything, or overwrite the normal html5 styles. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have figured out the problem, it had something to do with how I was sending the JSON data under

```
data-setup: '{controls:true}'
```

it should be formatted like

```
data-setup: '{"controls":true}'
```

then the rest is in the css file